# Convert a ResultSet into List of HashMap in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, logic

I have a resultset (returned by a stored procedure) like -

[image]

I need a List of HashMap, and HashMap will be made of individual (distinct by combination of FirstName, LastName and Id)  students records. Below image will describe the structure of HashMap.

[image]

So, basically in this example, I need a list of 3 HashMap.

Can you please suggest some efficient way to do that? Thanks!

**why do I need a list of hashmap for this?**

I need to create an XML file out of this ResultSet. List of HashMap is the best way I can think of for required XML structure.

**XML Structure :**

[image]

If my approach is not correct in terms of coding standard or efficiency, please suggest me different approach.

**What I am thinking:**

I've not tried yet. But can not think anything else other than iterating over the ResultSet and temporarily storing FirstName, LastName and Id to check if it is same as previous value or not. If same then add marks array to MarksList, else consider it as record of another student. I am hoping there might be a different way.

**[Update]:**

I think I should use list of Objects, not list of HashMap. But the question still is, how can I interpret the value from resultset and set values into the object.

Comment: Please share what you have already tried.

Comment: why do you need a list of hashmap for this?

Comment: You know you are using an OO language but managing your data all in lists and maps here. i.e. That's not a very OO approach. you would normally map the data to an object.

Comment: I've not tried yet. But can not think anything else other than iterating over the ResultSet and temporarily storing FirstName, LastName and Id to check if it is same as previous value or not. If same then add marks array to MarksList, else consider it as record of another student. I am hoping there might be a different way.

Comment: I'll share the final XML structure I need to create out of this data in a moment.

Comment: @Kartic I've provided a simple jaxb solution for creating the xml. Can you please edit your question to include the query you use to get the data, so that I can try to help you extract the data in the needed format. I can't see the picture of the resultset

Comment: @MihaiC Thanks for your effort. The first image is for resultset.

Comment: @Kartic edited my answer with complete solution for you. Just edit the parts where you get the data from the database, i used a simple query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Provided code to extract the data from the `ResultSet` correctly into the objects used by `JAXB`.

---

You don't need a `HashMap` and/or a `List` of `HashMap` to create a `xml` file
You can do this easily with [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/), provided you create the correct data objects.

First, create `classes` to match the structure desired to be in the `xml`.

1. a `ScoreRecord` class which holds the course information such as course name and mark.
2. a `Student` class which holds student info such as firstname, lastname and a list of `ScoreRecords` objects.
3. a `StudentGroup` class which holds all the students belonging to the same faculty group

The `ScoreRecord` class:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Mark")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "sub", "percent" })
public class ScoreRecord {
    private String sub;
    private String percent;

    public void setSub(String sub) {
        this.sub = sub;
    }

    public String getSub() {
        return sub;
    }

    public void setPercent(String percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    public String getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }
}
```

The `Student` class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "firstName", "lastName", "id", "scoreRecords" })
public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<ScoreRecord> scoreRecords;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "FirstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "LastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setScoreRecords(List<ScoreRecord> scoreRecords) {
        this.scoreRecords = scoreRecords;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "MarksList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Mark")
    public List<ScoreRecord> getScoreRecords() {
        return scoreRecords;
    }
}
```

The `StudentGroup` class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Records")
public class StudentGroup {
    private List<Student> students;

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "StudentRecord")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}
```

Now, create a class to hold the data "as is" from the database

```
public class DbStudent {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer id;
    private String sub;
    private String percent;

public DbStudent(String firstName, String lastName, int id, String sub, String percent) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.id = id;
    this.sub = sub;
    this.percent = percent;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setSub(String sub) {
    this.sub = sub;
}

public String getSub() {
    return sub;
}

public void setPercent(String percent) {
    this.percent = percent;
}

public String getPercent() {
    return percent;
}
```

}

Create a method to retrive the data as a `List` of this object type. I assume you already have something that gets the `ResultSet`, iterate it and `.add` to the list of `DbStudent` objects.

Something like:

```
public List<DbStudent> getStudents() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<DbStudent> entries = new ArrayList<DbStudent>();

    Class.forName(databaseDriver);
    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

    Statement sttm = this.connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = sttm.executeQuery("select * from TMP_STUDENT"); //in your case procedure call

    if (rs != null) {
        while (rs.next()) { //add the results into the list
            entries.add(new DbStudent(rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"), rs.getString("LASTNAME"), rs.getInt("ID"),
                                      rs.getString("SUB"), rs.getString("PERCENT")));

        }
        rs.close();
    }

    return entries;
}
```

Now, the main method. It contains logic to extract all the info from the list of database objects. Basically we sort it by id, iterate through it checking if we find or not a new student. If we find a new student, we add the previous one to a list of `Student` objects. This student already has his marks set.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    //get the data from the database as is
    OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ORACLE_DRIVER, ORACLE_CONN);
    List<DbStudent> dbStudentList = null;
    try {
        dbStudentList = myOracleConnection.getStudents(); //get the list of students from the procedure or query
        myOracleConnection.CloseConnection();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Stopping execution and exiting...");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Stopping execution and exiting...");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //sort the list on Id, so we can know when we find a new student
    Collections.sort(dbStudentList, new Comparator<DbStudent>() {
            public int compare(DbStudent s1, DbStudent s2) {
                return s1.getId().compareTo(s2.getId());
            }
        });

    List<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<Student>(); //list which will hold all the student objects

    Integer previousId = 0; //control variable
    List<ScoreRecord> marksList = new ArrayList<ScoreRecord>(); //list to store the marks for each student        
    Student s = null;

    for (int i=0;i<dbStudentList.size();i++) {

        if(i==dbStudentList.size()-1){ //if we reached the end, no more students after this record, set the marks and add the student to the list
            s.setScoreRecords(marksList);
            studentList.add(s);
        }

        if (dbStudentList.get(i).getId().compareTo(previousId) != 0) {
            //new student found
            if(s!=null){
                //if new student found add the previous one to the list after setting the marks
                s.setScoreRecords(marksList); 
                studentList.add(s);
            }
            s = new Student(); //create a new student
            s.setFirstName(dbStudentList.get(i).getFirstName());
            s.setId(dbStudentList.get(i).getId());
            s.setLastName(dbStudentList.get(i).getLastName());

            ScoreRecord sr = new ScoreRecord();
            sr.setSub(dbStudentList.get(i).getSub());
            sr.setPercent(dbStudentList.get(i).getPercent());

            marksList = new ArrayList<ScoreRecord>(); //reset marks list
            marksList.add(sr);
        } else {
            //same student
            ScoreRecord sr = new ScoreRecord();
            sr.setSub(dbStudentList.get(i).getSub());
            sr.setPercent(dbStudentList.get(i).getPercent());
            marksList.add(sr); //add mark to existing marks list
        }
        previousId=dbStudentList.get(i).getId(); //set the control variable to the new id
    }

    StudentGroup sg=new StudentGroup(); //create the student wrapper
    sg.setStudents(studentList); //add the student list to the wrapper

    //create xml with JAXB
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentGroup.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    m.marshal(sg, new File(STUDENT_XML));
}
```

The output of the `xml` is exactly how you want it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Records>
    <StudentRecord>
        <FirstName>AA1</FirstName>
        <LastName>BB1</LastName>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <MarksList>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Math</sub>
                <percent>51%</percent>
            </Mark>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Phy</sub>
                <percent>61%</percent>
            </Mark>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Bio</sub>
                <percent>61%</percent>
            </Mark>
        </MarksList>
    </StudentRecord>
    <StudentRecord>
        <FirstName>AA2</FirstName>
        <LastName>BB2</LastName>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <MarksList>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Bio</sub>
                <percent>62%</percent>
            </Mark>
        </MarksList>
    </StudentRecord>
    <StudentRecord>
        <FirstName>AA3</FirstName>
        <LastName>BB3</LastName>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <MarksList>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Math</sub>
                <percent>53%</percent>
            </Mark>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Phy</sub>
                <percent>63%</percent>
            </Mark>
            <Mark>
                <sub>Chem</sub>
                <percent>63%</percent>
            </Mark>
        </MarksList>
    </StudentRecord>
</Records>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Thanks!

Comment: @Kartic no problem, there is probably a better way to get the data from the resultset in the desired format, but that's what i came up with in short notice. if you do find a better way, let me know, i'd like to see it

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is correct Data object. Here it should Student record  which internally should hold the list of score records
which will have id,FirstName , LastName, scoreRecords(it should be list holding subject name, marks, % etc).

Then simply convert it into XML with JAXB

Comment: Can you give me some suggestion on how to create scoreRecords out of this resultset

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your sql-statement/storedprocedure by LastName and FirstName you don't need to collect the whole data in memory.
Simply iterate your resultset and collect the data until FirstName and LastName changes, than aggregate your sub and percent data and stream it directly to a file or a dom. And so on....

Or change the stored procedure or create a new one in that way that it already aggregates the data for you.